# C#: Go through Nested Properties Safely without Error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am looking through reflection metadata properties, and adding certain attributes to all Actions in API Controller. First checking Level 1 of properties, see if it exists, and then precede to level 2 of properties.

Sonarqube is giving warning below. The thing is, I want to safely check 1 level before preceding to next, or program produces error. If combining several if statements in 1 line at runtime, can't compiler suddenly scramble the sequence of if statements, giving an error? What is the safe way to conduct this? Additionally, if people are refactoring code, does it makes the code sequence more legible?

> Warning: Merge this if statement with the enclosing one.

```
foreach (ActionModel action in controller.Actions)
{
    if (action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments.Any())   // Level 1 
    {
        if (action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments().Any())  //Level 2
        {
            returnType = action.ActionMethod.ReturnType.GenericTypeArguments[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would the compiler reorder your code?

Comment: well thought if statements are in one line, can it randomly execute any given?  additionally if that isn't true, isn't it better when person refactors code? they can visibly see the true order? trying to understand myself

Comment: The C# compiler emits your code in order it appears as text. Technically the JIT or CPU can change the order of execution of some instructions, but it analyzes the code first to make sure that it won't break. The contract of `&&` is such that the code on the left will always execute before the code on the right, so it's 100% safe to do a bounds check on the left and then read from the array on the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be no unpredictability.

After merging the `if` statements, the conditional will look like:

```
expr1 && expr2
```

With operator `&&`, the expressions are always evaluated from left to right. If `expr1` evaluates to `false`, then `expr2` will never be evaluated.

Comment: thanks, this really helps, now for refactoring, isn't a sequential sequence of if statements better or above method better? want to understand best coding practice

Comment: this way person who is refactoring code, can visibly see the order, or is that not true? want to learn myself

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 It might better from a performance POV to have a single branch, but if this comes at the expense of code-clarity, then you're really not losing much by passing through two branches instead. Unless it's a code hot-spot, it's really just a style decision.

Comment: ok, I will keep it then, feel Sonarqube can overdo things at times, if both ways are good, and one has more code clarity, I will keep two ifs, we have many developers changing things, and want sequence to be important, thanks

Comment: @spender the IL generated will [be identical](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgPgAgTARgLACgYGYAE9MGFUDeqmJ2WMALJgPIB2ApgJIBmAFAJTGlEql+ZhmmVgEEOmAGQTMAIQ6de/EjyVKYCAJysARCMwBDWgBNZ29gG4uSgL5XMtxSTt2M2KgBUA7gHsWHOyqqgsJi7AqqmIERJMGscmF2EVHRfOpaugbGphaJqg4R+aSFTo6YAPRlmABK9CYsADSyEACu9JgszqUARt7eEJihmAC8AHyYwAAWAE7enpi0zRAQlqV2PX2y4qPj07Pzi8uo1kA=) so there is no effect on performance.

Comment: @yaakov Agreed. In which case, let's pick another metric and substitute `"It might better from a performance POV"` with `"It might better from a code-nesting POV"` :)